# Multiple statements query SPARQL 1.1 property-paths Virtuoso 7.2.X

Tags: rdf, sparql, virtuoso

A sample RDF dataset has entries `owl#NamedIndividual` grouped by `owl#Class` and a custom relation named `IsMemberOf`. When I try to obtain a list of results segregated by their type, it works well but the moment I add a way to obtain their corresponding `IsMemberOf` I don't get expected results.

Here is three SPARQL 1.1 queries I gave to Virtuoso (sample dataset below):

Query 1

```
sparql select * from <test>
where {
#If I uncomment the next line I don't get the proper results
#  ?s <IsMemberOf> ?member_of.
  ?s rdfs:label ?name.
  {
    ?s rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* <livingthings>.
  } UNION {
    ?s a <rock>.
  }
};
```

Query 2

```
sparql select * from <test>
where {
#If I uncomment the next line I get no results at all
#   ?s <IsMemberOf> ?member_of.
    ?s rdfs:label ?name.
    ?s rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* <livingthings>.
};
```

Query 3

```
sparql select * from <test>
where {
  ?s <IsMemberOf> ?member_of.
  ?s rdfs:label ?name.
  ?s rdf:type <dog>.
#If I replace the previous line with the next line I get no results at all
# ?s rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* <livingthings>.
};
```

This is how the data is grouped:

```
livingthings
->mammal
--->dog
----->doggy_the_dog
----->fido_the_dog
--->cat
---->katy_the_cat
--->elephant
----->eli_the_elephant
->reptile
--->snake
----->snakey_the_snake
nonlivingthings
->rock
--->rocky_the_rock
--->ralf_the_rock

group_a
->rocky_the_rock
->ralf_the_rock
->snakey_the_snake
->doggy_the_dog
group_b
->fido_the_dog
->katy_the_cat
group_c
->eli_the_elephant
```

Finaly here is the data I used

```
sparql create silent graph <test>;
sparql insert into graph <test> {
  <nonlivingthings> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class>.
  <nonlivingthings> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "Non-living things".
  <rock> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class>.
  <rock> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "Rock".
  <rock> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf> <nonlivingthings>.
  <rocky_the_rock> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual>.
  <rocky_the_rock> <IsMemberOf> <group_a>.
  <rocky_the_rock> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <rock>.
  <rocky_the_rock> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "Rocky the rock".
  <ralf_the_rock> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual>.
  <ralf_the_rock> <IsMemberOf> <group_a>.
  <ralf_the_rock> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <rock>.
  <ralf_the_rock> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "Ralf the rock".  
  <livingthings> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class>.
  <livingthings> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "Living things".
  <mammal> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class>.
  <mammal> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "Mammal".
  <mammal> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf> <livingthings>.
  <reptile> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class>.
  <reptile> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "Reptile".
  <reptile> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf> <livingthings>.
  <dog> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class>.
  <dog> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "Dog".
  <dog> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf> <mammal>.
  <cat> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class>.
  <cat> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "Cat".
  <cat> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf> <mammal>.
  <elephant> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class>.
  <elephant> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "Elephant".
  <elephant> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf> <mammal>.
  <snake> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class>.
  <snake> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "Snake".
  <snake> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf> <reptile>.
  <snakey_the_snake> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual>.
  <snakey_the_snake> <IsMemberOf> <group_a>.
  <snakey_the_snake> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <snake>.
  <snakey_the_snake> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "Snakey the snake".
  <doggy_the_dog> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual>.
  <doggy_the_dog> <IsMemberOf> <group_a>.
  <doggy_the_dog> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <dog>.
  <doggy_the_dog> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "Doggy the dog".
  <fido_the_dog> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual>.
  <fido_the_dog> <IsMemberOf> <group_b>.
  <fido_the_dog> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <dog>.
  <fido_the_dog> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "Fido the dog".
  <katy_the_cat> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual>.
  <katy_the_cat> <IsMemberOf> <group_b>.
  <katy_the_cat> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <cat>.
  <katy_the_cat> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "Katy the cat".
  <eli_the_elephant> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual>.
  <eli_the_elephant> <IsMemberOf> <group_c>.
  <eli_the_elephant> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <elephant>.
  <eli_the_elephant> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "Eli the elephant".
};
```

Why do I only get the following incomplet result when I uncomment `?s <IsMemberOf> ?member_of.` in query one?

```
s               member_of   name
rocky_the_rock  group_a     Rocky the rock
ralf_the_rock   group_a     Ralf the rock
```

All of the results under the `<livingthings>` class are left out. Is it because of a bug in Virtuoso or the way my SPARQL query is formed?

Comment: It's worth flagging Virtuoso's SPASQL -- SPARQL-in-SQL; used in ODBC, JDBC, ADO.NET, OLE DB, and other SQL-based connections -- queries as such. The leading `sparql` and trailing `;` will confuse people who are expecting to just see SPARQL.  You can also strip those, and do everything you did here through the SPARQL interface -- `http://virtuoso-host:port/sparql/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtuoso seems to handle user defined relation oddly in a query when mixed with a property path.

Here is the Virtuoso specific way to address this issue.

Query 1 answer

```
sparql select * from <test>
where {
  ?s rdfs:label ?name.
  {
    ?s <IsMemberOf>{1} ?member_of.
    ?s rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* <livingthings>.
  } UNION {
    ?s <IsMemberOf>{1} ?member_of.
    ?s a <rock>.
  }
};
```

Query 2 answer

```
sparql select * from <test>
where {
    ?s <IsMemberOf>{1} ?member_of.
    ?s rdfs:label ?name.
    ?s rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* <livingthings>.
};
```

Applying an explicit property path for the user defined relation as such `?s <IsMemberOf>{1} ?member_of.` gives the expected results.

In query one the line `?s <IsMemberOf>{1} ?member_of.` is applied to each term inside each union element. If not then the results are not as desired. It does solve the issue but it is a bit nonsensical. That is why I'll leave the question open for a few days to see if anyone can provide logical explanation to why things are that way in Virtuoso. If it's just a bug I'll contact them via their mailing list.

Comment: If this persists in current Virtuoso (Open Source and/or Commercial) 7.2.1, and if you haven't yet reported it, please do so -- on the [mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/mailman/virtuoso-users/), [discussion forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), [github project](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/), or in a [support case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).

Answer (score 1):

It's tough to say exactly what the problem here is.  The queries you've shown aren't legal SPARQL by themselves (e.g., in SPARQL you do `select ...`, not `sparql select ...;`), but that might be the Virtuoso interface you're using.  Another possible issue is that `<IsMemberOf>` and similar are relative IRIs, and how they get resolved may be different between the data loading and the query processing, etc., so it's not necessarily the case that `<IsMemberOf>` in one place actually refers to the same IRI that `<IsMemberOf>` refers to in another. You really should use absolute IRIs. I don't know whether or not that's the problem here.

That said, I took your data and resolved the IRIs against **http://example.org/** so that they're all absolute, and it looks like the queries work the way you'd want them to.  E.g., running the following queries with Jena works just fine.

```sql
base <http://example.org/>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select * where {
  ?s <IsMemberOf> ?member_of.
  ?s rdfs:label ?name.
  ?s a/rdfs:subClassOf* <livingthings>.
}
```

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| s                  | member_of | name               |
=======================================================
| <doggy_the_dog>    | <group_a> | "Doggy the dog"    |
| <eli_the_elephant> | <group_c> | "Eli the elephant" |
| <fido_the_dog>     | <group_b> | "Fido the dog"     |
| <katy_the_cat>     | <group_b> | "Katy the cat"     |
| <snakey_the_snake> | <group_a> | "Snakey the snake" |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Here's the updated data:

```
<http://example.org/elephant>
        a       <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class> ;
        <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label>
                "Elephant" ;
        <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf>
                <http://example.org/mammal> .

<http://example.org/snakey_the_snake>
        a       <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual> , <http://example.org/snake> ;
        <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label>
                "Snakey the snake" ;
        <http://example.org/IsMemberOf>
                <http://example.org/group_a> .

<http://example.org/cat>
        a       <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class> ;
        <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label>
                "Cat" ;
        <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf>
                <http://example.org/mammal> .

<http://example.org/mammal>
        a       <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class> ;
        <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label>
                "Mammal" ;
        <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf>
                <http://example.org/livingthings> .

<http://example.org/katy_the_cat>
        a       <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual> , <http://example.org/cat> ;
        <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label>
                "Katy the cat" ;
        <http://example.org/IsMemberOf>
                <http://example.org/group_b> .

<http://example.org/fido_the_dog>
        a       <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual> , <http://example.org/dog> ;
        <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label>
                "Fido the dog" ;
        <http://example.org/IsMemberOf>
                <http://example.org/group_b> .

<http://example.org/dog>
        a       <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class> ;
        <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label>
                "Dog" ;
        <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf>
                <http://example.org/mammal> .

<http://example.org/eli_the_elephant>
        a       <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual> , <http://example.org/elephant> ;
        <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label>
                "Eli the elephant" ;
        <http://example.org/IsMemberOf>
                <http://example.org/group_c> .

<http://example.org/reptile>
        a       <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class> ;
        <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label>
                "Reptile" ;
        <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf>
                <http://example.org/livingthings> .

<http://example.org/nonlivingthings>
        a       <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class> ;
        <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label>
                "Non-living things" .

<http://example.org/livingthings>
        a       <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class> ;
        <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label>
                "Living things" .

<http://example.org/doggy_the_dog>
        a       <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual> , <http://example.org/dog> ;
        <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label>
                "Doggy the dog" ;
        <http://example.org/IsMemberOf>
                <http://example.org/group_a> .

<http://example.org/rocky_the_rock>
        a       <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual> , <http://example.org/rock> ;
        <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label>
                "Rocky the rock" ;
        <http://example.org/IsMemberOf>
                <http://example.org/group_a> .

<http://example.org/rock>
        a       <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class> ;
        <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label>
                "Rock" ;
        <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf>
                <http://example.org/nonlivingthings> .

<http://example.org/ralf_the_rock>
        a       <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual> , <http://example.org/rock> ;
        <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label>
                "Ralf the rock" ;
        <http://example.org/IsMemberOf>
                <http://example.org/group_a> .

<http://example.org/snake>
        a       <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class> ;
        <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label>
                "Snake" ;
        <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf>
                <http://example.org/reptile> .
```

Comment: Yes the "sparql select" instead of "sparl" are Virtuoso specific artifacts. The data uses relative IRIs because I wanted something shorter, I should of used prefixes. Thank you for testing out the data and queries in Jena it helped me confirm proper use of SPARQL 1.1. The problem is specific to Virtuoso and I've found a solution.